# How Android can distinguish shape by camera?

Tags: android

My thought is like this: user open camera on a clothes. How to distinguish and grasp clothes's shape automatically? Maybe later save clothes as a picture(without margin). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With great difficulty; you might want to start by looking at OpenCV for Android.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's written in C. Need to do some extra works before use it in eclipse + ADT. PS: any other similar java library I use directly?